# Assets does not see subfolders

Tags: flutter

assets does not see subfolders.
If folder `/image.png` - then all the rules.
If folder `/subfolder/image.png` - writes:
Unable to load asset

Is there a solution or is it supported?

Required for offline maps in flutter_map.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had similar problem when started, and my problem was:

Add asset file to pubspec, like

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - subfolder/image.png
```

Then using it like `AssetImage('mage.png')`

The problem here was that you should still provide the full path, as in: `AssetImage(subfolder/image.png)`

Please check [AssetImage class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/AssetImage-class.html) for more examples.

Answer (score 21):

All you need is to provide all folders and subfolders.

Check official [doc](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images):

> Note that only files located directly in the directory will be
>   included; to add files located in subdirectories, create an entry per
>   directory.

But if you need to provide different scales (like 1.5x, 2.0x, 3.0x) you don't need to mention these subfolders in pubspec.yaml.

Comment: Hope they address this, this is completely dumb 

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what the problem is exactly, but you need to list every folder that contains assets. The files in the listed folder and in resolution sub-folders (like `1.5x/`, `2.0x`, `3.0x`, ...) are then found automatically,
but other sub-folders are ignored.